# TypeScript - React context does not work with new PropTypes package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

The following code that uses `React.PropTypes` works fine, however it produces the expected warning (Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated...):

```
import * as React from 'react';

export class BackButton extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    static contextTypes = {
        router: React.PropTypes.object
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.goBack}>Back</button>
        );
    }

    goBack = () => {
        this.context.router.history.goBack();
    }
}
```

If I now replace `React.PropTypes` with the new `PropTypes` package, I get a TypeError: "Cannot read property 'object' of undefined":

```
import * as React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export class BackButton extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    static contextTypes = {
        router: PropTypes.object
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.goBack}>Back</button>
        );
    }

    goBack = () => {
        this.context.router.history.goBack();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you install PropTypes by npm?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's not the proper way to import `prop-types` using TypeScript.

You have to use

`import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';`

instead of

`import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`

[webpackbin](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KplE7P3QsamGiyBPsGH)

Comment: Thanks @QoP, that was exactly it.

Comment: FFS just spent far too long stuck on this. Problem I think is that lack of a d.ts file meant I couldn't peek into prop-types and see that it needed a * as syntax for importing.